# What is the the maximum and minimum of a sequence of $n$ random variables having Chi-squared distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, distribution-tails, extreme-value-theorem

Say we have a sequence of $n$ random variables $[X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n]$, identically distributed, having Chi-squared distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom. Then, what is the upper bound of $\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\max}\{X_i\}$ and lower bound of $\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\min} \{X_i\}$. For example, we know that if $X_i$ is Gaussian distributed with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$, then $\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\max}\{X_i\}\leq \sigma\sqrt{2\log n}$. Are there similar results (upper and lower bounds) when $X_i$ is chi-squared distributed?
Any help or reference to existing theory would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you mean bounds on the means of the max and min, not bounds on the max and min themselves, correct?

Comment: Yes we can start with investigating the expected value of max and min of $X_i$. Then see if the bounds change without the expectation? @Golden_Ratio

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about bounds on the maximum or minimum here. The support of the maximum $n$ i.i.d random variables is the same as the support of each of the random variables, so in particular, they (the max/min) can assume arbitrarily large/small values.